# Why is there no "unanswered" tab for search results?

Tags: support, search, unanswered-questions

I was searching for questions related to a subject and noticed that the "unanswered" tab isn't present for search results:

[image]

---

But when searching based on a tag, the tab is there:

[image]

---

I was wondering why is it so? I know unanswered questions can be filtered by adding search parameters, but what is the reason for this difference?

Comment: Use `[genymotion] answers:0`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The unanswered tab applies to *questions only* and the tab is thus available only on tag pages. Search results normally include answers too.

If you meant to search for the *tag*, then use the `[tagname]` syntax and you'll be taken to a tag page (you can combine tags, including using `or` inbetween).

You can search for questions with 0 answers too, by adding `is:question answers:0` to your query. Or you can find questions without an accepted answer by searching for `is:question hasaccepted:0`. This then gives you results *like* the *Unanswered* tab would give you. See the [help pages on search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for more details.

Comment: You can also add `closed:0` for better search results.

Comment: I actually didn't know that search included answers as well! (It maybe because I've mostly seen `Q:...` results). Having answers in the results explains that lack of unanswered tab. Thanks for the clarification.